# Error al crear y executar procedimiento almacenado

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedure, sql

Estoy tratando de crear un procedimiento almacenado el cual verifica todos los proyectos de mi base de datos y me da por cada proyecto una serie de elementos que necesito.

Al intentar hacer esto, el procedimiento me aroja un error `Must declare the scalar variable "@ProjTitle".`

Yo ya la variable la declare, pero no se porque me esta arojando este error.

Aqui esta mi codigo.

Saludos

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @ProjID VARCHAR(100) -- ProjectID
DECLARE @ProjTitle VARCHAR(256) -- Project Title
DECLARE @ProjCat VARCHAR(256) -- Project Category
DECLARE @ProjSubCat VARCHAR(20) -- Project Subcategory
DECLARE @TasksTable nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @TaskDetailsTable nvarchar(256)
DECLARE @sql nvarchar(max)

DECLARE GetTasks CURSOR FOR  
SELECT Project.ProjectID, ProjectVersion.Title , CV1.CategoryName as Category, CV2.CategoryName as SubCategory
From Project LEFT JOIN ProjectVersion ON Project.ProjectID = ProjectVersion.ProjectID LEFT JOIN CategoryVersion AS CV1 ON Project.CategoryID = CV1.CategoryID AND
ProjectVersion.VersionLanguage = CV1.VersionLanguage
LEFT JOIN CategoryVersion AS CV2 ON Project.SubcategoryID = CV2.CategoryID AND
ProjectVersion.VersionLanguage = CV2.VersionLanguage

OPEN GetTasks
FETCH NEXT FROM GetTasks INTO @ProjID, @ProjTitle, @ProjCat, @ProjSubCat

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN
  set @TasksTable =  '['+@ProjID+'Tasks]'
  set @TaskDetailsTable =  '['+@ProjID+'TaskDetails]'

  set @sql = 'SELECT Distinct @ProjTitle, @ProjCat, @ProjSubCat, TT.StartDate
        FROM Project, '+ @TasksTable+' as TT where Project.ProjectID = @ProjID
        and TT.ProjectID = Project.ProjectID'
  EXECUTE sp_executesql @sql
END

CLOSE GetTasks
DEALLOCATE GetTasks
```

Comment: Y, ¿Cómo te ha ido con tu problema?

Answer (score 1):

Te recomendaría que vieras bien la necesidad de usar dynamic SQL y cursores.
Pero yendo directo a tu código, el problema es que las variables las estás usando **dentro** del código dinámico, y tus variables son válidas fuera del mismo.

Afortunadamente, `sp_executesql` puede usarse pensando en esta forma, sólo debes reemplazar tu líne por la siguiente:

```
EXECUTE sp_executesql 
              @sql, 
              N'@ProjTitle VARCHAR(256), @ProjCat VARCHAR(256), @ProjSubCat VARCHAR(20), @ProjID VARCHAR(100)', 
              @ProjTitle, 
              @ProjCat, 
              @ProjSubCat,
              @ProjID
;
```

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58855/discussion-on-answer-by-lamak-error-al-crear-y-executar-procedimiento-almacenado).